# Why does "+" require "RangeReplaceableCollection?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to implement a struct, called "Dual", and overload the arithmetic operators on it. I want it to work for Integers and Doubles, so am hoping that defining it generically will help with that, . At the moment I have:

```
struct Dual<Element: Numeric> {
    var f: Element
    var fPrime: Element

    init(_ f: Element, _ fPrime: Element) {
        self.f = f
        self.fPrime = fPrime
    }

    static func + (left: Dual, right: Dual) -> Dual {
        return Dual(left.f + right.f, left.fPrime + right.fPrime)
    }
}
```

But I get the compiler error:

```
Referencing operator function '+' on 'RangeReplaceableCollection' requires that 'Numeric' conform to 'RangeReplaceableCollection'
```

I work out what the suggestion protocol has to do with struct, it's just an ordered pair.

Can anyone suggest what I need to do? Thanks!

Comment: I don't get any error when I run this in the playground... What version of Swift/Xcode are you using?

Comment: @Sweeper A function/derivative pair. I've also defined -, \*, /. For - I those I get a different error, "Referencing operator function '*' on 'FloatingPoint' requires that 'Numeric' conform to 'FloatingPoint'".

Xcode 11.4.1, same errors in 5.2 and 5.3.

Comment: Can you show a [mcve]? `/` is understandable because `Numeric` doesn't support `/`

Comment: @Sweeper interestingly if I copy the above code into a new Project, it will build fine apart from the ```/```, which still errors. Any ideas why A) the original is caught in this Range error, and B) what protocol I would need to if Numeric doesn't support ```/```?

Comment: ```/``` code:
```static func / (left: Dual, right: Dual) -> Dual {
        return Dual(
            left.f / right.f,
            (left.fPrime*right.f - right.fPrime*left.f) / (right.f*right.f)
        )
    }```